# Perl using `IO::Handle` or `IO::File` when not reading actual files

Tags: perl, file-io

I like using `IO::File` to open and read files rather than the built in way.

#### Built In Way

```
 open my $fh, "<", $flle or die;
```

#### IO::File

```
 use IO::File;

 my $fh = IO::File->new( $file, "r" );
```

However, what if I am treating the output of a command as my *file*?

The built in `open` function allows me to do this:

```
open my $cmd_fh, "-|", "zcat $file.gz" or die;

while ( my $line < $cmd_fh > ) {
    chomp $line;
}
```

What would be the equivalent of `IO::File` or `IO::Handle`?

By the way, I know can do this:

```
open my $cmd_fh,  "-|", "zcat $file.gz" or die;
my $cmd_obj = IO::File-> new_from_fd( fileno( $cmd_fh ), 'r' );
```

But then why bother with `IO::File` if there's already a file handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open them just like in `open`, because that's exactly what `IO::File` does - it initializes `IO::Handle` object and links it to file opened with Perl's native `open`.

```
use IO::File;

if (my $fh = new IO::File('dmesg|')) {
   print <$fh>;
   $fh->close;
}
```

`IO::File` is really just a pretty wrapper. If what it does not complex enough for you, you can just go and init `IO::Handle` from any FD you like yourself. You need rest of IO::* OO functionality, I suppose, so who cares how does initializer looks?

Comment: This answers my question. Unfortunately, this has the same issue as the two parameter form of the `open` command and the reason we were told to go to the three parameter form. I like `IO::File` because I can control whether to slurp the entire file at once into an array or a single line. (`IO::File->getline` vs `IO::File->getlines`).

Comment: @DavidW., you know that you can do it without `IO::File` too, right? `my $one_line = <$fh>` will read one line.

Comment: But `@foo = <$fh>` reads multiple lines while `@foo = $fh->get line` still only reads a single line. Also, `$foo = $fh->get_lines` doesn't read one line, but an entire file while `$foo = <$fh>` reads only a single line. I'm not depending upon the context on how my reads work.

Comment: I tried `$io->open("zcat foo.gz", "-|")` since the documentation says that the second parameter is the _mode_, and it looked like it would work when peeking at `IO::File`, but `IO::Handle` doesn't recognize `-|` and `|-` as a mode.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your snippet fails if `$file` contains spaces or other special characters.

```
open my $cmd_fh,  "-|", "zcat $file.gz" or die $!;
```

should be

```
open my $cmd_fh,  "-|", "zcat", "$file.gz" or die $!;
```

or

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
open my $cmd_fh,  "-|", shell_quote("zcat", "$file.gz") or die $!;
```

or

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
open my $cmd_fh,  shell_quote("zcat", "$file.gz")."|" or die $!;
```

I mention the latter variants because passing a single arg to `IO::File->open` boils down to passing that arg to `open($fh, $that_arg)`, so you could use

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
IO::File->open(shell_quote("zcat", "$file.gz")."|") or die $!;
```

---

If all you want is to use IO::File's methods, you don't need to use `IO::File->open`.

```
use IO::Handle qw( );  # Needed on older versions of Perl
open my $cmd_fh,  "-|", "zcat", "$file.gz" or die $!;

$cmd_fh->autoflush(1);  # Example.
$cmd_fh->print("foo");  # Example.
```

Comment: I personally would still prefer to init from FD and avoid entire quoting problem and calling shell at all.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, Aside from the fact that the OP's init from fd code still uses a shell, that's silly. If you're going to use `open`, you don't need to use IO::File at all. Keep in mind that the `open` builtin creates an IO::File object (or IO::Handle in older versions of Perl).

Comment: Err... no. Native open returns `GLOB`. Maybe right now it is `IO::File` inside relevant GLOB's slot, but it is not mentioned anywhere in docs, and I wouldn't count on undocumented behavior.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, Did you try it before contradicting me? It is definitely supported behaviour on which you can rely. (They've even improved it recently so the module gets loaded automatically.) If it's not mentioned in the docs, then that's a bug.

Comment: Of course. `ref` returns `IO::File` and `GLOB` respectively. But EVEN if they'd return same thing, let me stress again: **it is not guaranteed anywhere in docs**.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, I never said `ref` was `IO::File`. The contradiction was the "Err... no." // If you want some documentation, see my update. Again, **that it's not in the docs is a bug because this is a supported feature**. And it's been a feature since at least 5.8. I think 5.6.

Comment: Interesting discussion and answer. However, my point was to avoid the builtin `open` command entirely. I know underneath that new versions of Perl use `IO::Handle` under `open` (or maybe the other way around. However, if I'm going object oriented, I'd like to do so in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use pipes with `IO::Handle`, you can use [`IO::Pipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Pipe.html) module.

Comment: IO::Pipe can't be used to spawn a process.